# How to use jq to convert an bash array in command line to json array?

Tags: jq

```
$ jq -c -n -e '[$x, $y]' --argjson x '"a"' --argjson y '"b"'
["a","b"]
```

I know that I could do something like the above. If I want to generate a json array from bash array, like the following. Is there a way to do so with an arbitrary length of arguments?

```
$ jq {some jq arguments} a b c # the bash array can be of an arbitrary length.
["a","b","c"]
```

Note a,b,c are not quoted in the command line as I want the input to be simple.

Comment: `jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args a b c` should output `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: @muru This looks good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main ways to create a valid JSON array from arbitrary lists of strings.  One is using `jq` with its `--args` option:

```bash
jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${mylist[@]}"
```

or, if the elements are not to be encoded as strings (they may be plain numbers, for example, or previously prepared JSON strings or whole JSON objects),

```bash
jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --jsonargs "${mylist[@]}"
```

Note that `--args` and `--jsonargs` and its arguments need to be the last thing on the command line of `jq`.

I'm using `-n` to disable reading any external input and `-c` to create JSON in the "compact" output format, as shown in the question.

The other way is using `jo`, a tool specifically made to make it easy to generate JSON on the command line:

```bash
jo -a "${mylist[@]}"
```

The `-a` option to `jo` generates an array from the given arguments.

The `jo` tool infers the type of the object itself, so a list like

```bash
mylist=(1 2 3 4 5 b)
```

would be turned into the JSON array

```json
[1,2,3,4,5,"b"]
```